# VLC | video as wallpaper | wallpaper stays in foreground hiding the taskbar and desktop icons

Tags: vlc, wallpaper

I am using VLC to set a video as my desktop wallpaper on windows 10.
What is happening: VLC runs the video as desktop wallpaper, but the video stays in the foreground and is always hiding my taskbar and desktop icons.
When i press the Windows Key from keyboard, it shows the taskbar temporarily as long as the video is out of focus (desktop icons are still hidden).

What i want to happen:
I want the video in the background (as wallpaper) with my desktop icons and taskbar always visible.
I mean the video should run in the background (not in the foreground) like a normal wallpaper (it stays in the background).

The script i am using in a batch file is:

```
@echo off
title MyTitle

start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --fullscreen --no-video-title-show --no-embedded-video --no-qt-fs-controller --qt-start-minimized --qt-system-tray --video-wallpaper --playlist-autostart --playlist-tree "C:\Users\User\Desktop\VLC\List"
```

is there a way to achieve that?

Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: You should ask this on StackExchange instead of SO. Try the SuperUser community

Comment: Sure, Thank you.